# Mist Wallet: How to increase desired fee?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, mist

I put in an ether transaction through that had a pretty low fee limit.  I didn't quite understand the alert that the program showed during the confirm step of the payment, but there could have been something there.

Anyways, the transaction is pending for 1 day now with 0 confirmations.  I can see it on etherscan.  I have been doing some reading.  I would like to try to increase the fee that I want to pay to see if that will help getting my transaction through the bottleneck ( #ucking cats! ).

How can I do this?  I have just read [a nice how-to about how to do this using the geth app interface](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@crusam/guide-on-how-to-deal-with-stucked-ethereum-transactions).  Does anyone have experience with this technique?  Does it work?  Is there an easier way through the Mist Wallet interface?

Thanks so much.

Mist Wallet v 0.9.3

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Mist has a similar tool, but I would recommend using [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/). From https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html:

> During times of extremely high volume (like we've seen during the Bancor and Status Token Contribution periods), transactions could be pending for hours, if not days, before being mined.
>
> During these times it is theoretically possible to replace an existing transaction with a new transaction with a higher gas price.
>
> The second transaction, theoretically, will be mined before the first transaction, effectively "canceling" the first transaction.
>
> The easiest way to do this is by sending a 0 ETH transaction to your own address with the same nonce and higher gas price. This will "cancel" your first transaction.
>
> There is no guarantee this will work, nor that it will work every time. This tool is very, very new. Please use at your own risk.

Comment: That's great insite.

Comment: I did try MyEtherWallet.  Also came across a post which explains how to use ethereal to clear stagnant transactions.  Mine eventually just got dropped from the system, and MyEtherWallet helped me send the funds.  The Mist Wallet seems broken and clunky to me.  https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/releasing-stuck-ethereum-transactions-1390149f297d